Fixing a Model for 3D Printing - Many Analysis Issues
So I have a cylinder I put a texture on in Blender and I want to export it but STLs are coming out horrible and IGES is not working either. Looks like there is some inverted faces but I can't seem to select them all at one to flip them. Re-calculate normals is not working either.
I am extremely new to Blender so please explain it to me like I'm 5. Thank you so much.


Hello and welcome. Please use a title that matches the content of the post. It should read like a question, be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the problem so that anyone searching for similar issues is likely to find this. Remove anything superfluous, avoid using words like "this", "help with", "issue" or "question about", instead describe what "it" is. Remember, your title is the first thing visitors see, answers you get depend heavily on it. See What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"
